# В чем некорректность запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица `marks` с полями:

- `id`
- `st_id`
- `d_id`
- `t_id`
- `mark`

Необходимо создать запрос, который выведет процент двоек, выставленных каждым учителем.

Решил, что процент будет выводиться из таблицы получаемой в следующем запросе (выводит `id` препода, кол - во двоек, кол - во всех оценок препода):

```
SELECT t_id, COUNT(mark) AS bad_marks FROM marks WHERE mark IN(2),
COUNT(mark) AS total_quantity FROM marks // тут пишет неправильный синтакс 
GROUP BY t_id;
```

При этом если выводить кол - во 3, 4, 5 первой строчкой - выводит, ставишь условие "двойка" - пишет "empty set" (двоек действительно нет, но почему не пишет, что их 0). Правильно ли я вообще начал и что не так.

Очень нужна Ваша помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: так уже ж есть один from, и where, а ты после них пытаешься count вызвать

Comment: а как тогдасделать правильно?

Comment: Сначала речь идет о  id, st_id, d_id, t_id, mark, а потом о двойках и учителях. Ответ на такой вопрос получить крайне сложно.

Comment: @ilyaplot, id - оценки, st_id -  студента, d_id - дисциплины, t_id - препода, mark - сама оценка

Comment: Или можо сразу без этой промежуточной таблици?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT mm.t_id, COUNT(mm.mark) AS bad_marks, 
(SELECT COUNT(m.mark) FROM marks AS m WHERE m.t_id=mm.t_id) AS total_quantity 
FROM marks AS mm WHERE mm.mark IN(2) GROUP BY mm.t_id;
```

Например, можно так. Ещё можно придумать варианты.

```
SELECT t_id, COUNT(mark) AS total_quantity, COUNT(IF(mark=2,mark,NULL)) AS bad_marks 
FROM marks GROUP BY t_id;
```

За второй вариант не отвечаю. Пробуйте

Comment: Вы знаете, второй вариант работает вполне правильно. Но у меня будет к Вам еще один вопрос,сейчас сформулирую

Comment: Если мне нужен процент двоек от всех оценок каждого из преподов, тогда мне стоит писать такой запрос??? **SELECT t_id, (SELECT bad_marks/total_quantity *100) AS percent FROM (SELECT t_id, COUNT(mark) AS total_quantity, COUNT(IF(mark=2,mark,NULL)) AS bad_marks  FROM marks GROUP BY t_id) GROUP BY t_id;**

Comment: Запутался с лишним GROUP BY, и можно ли сократить запрос, оптимизировать его? Прошу проявить терпение, с MySQL начал разбираться недавно.

Comment: Скорее `SELECT t_id, COUNT(mark) AS total_quantity, COUNT(IF(mark=2,mark,NULL)) AS bad_marks, (bad_marks / total_quantity * 100) AS percent FROM marks GROUP BY t_id;`. Если такой вариант не прокатит, то замените в `percent` `bad_marks` и `total_quantity` на `COUNT(IF(mark=2,mark,NULL))` и `COUNT(mark)`

Comment: Помогло, второй вариант с заменой, а почему так, Не могли бы Вы объяснить. Хотелось бы знать этот момент. Выходит что этих значений MySQL не увидел???

Comment: Или выходит что в таблице marks нету значений bad_marks, total_quantity изначально?

Comment: поэтому и ошибка

Comment: Именно поэтому и ошибка

Comment: еще раз спасибо